What is the use of LEDs connected in series in this circuit?
I don't know something about working of the opamp in the welder circuit.  Can someone explain it me please?


I'd have to measure some voltages to confirm my suspicion but it could be used for clamping since the forward voltage drop would be rather substantial and then having two LEDs like that would essentially double that voltage drop. The LEDs may also help in limiting current or monitoring the current flow through parts of the circuit. The LEDs will illuminate when the current is sufficient to cause the necessary forward voltage drop across them, potentially indicating normal operation or fault conditions.

The opamp can have a hard clamp in both directions with orthodox back to back Zeners. Series resistance can soften the clamp action. This is done here. The LED in the forward direction is not a bad Zener. You can use a LED as a Zener for a unidirectional clamp. The series connection is this case doubles the clamp voltage and doubles the reverse voltage rating and provides some visual indication of circuit status.

Thanks. I found some helpful information here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/744418/lm6171-how-to-keep-the-op-amp-off-its-saturation-region
